# Are passive scanners subset of active scanners?

Tags: networking

**Assuming:**

> Passive scanners are those which do not actively send request packets, all they can do is monitor packets (which can be probe replies and beacon frames) which are passing through the interface and analyze followed by some action(s)

> Active scanners are those which sends broadcasts/probe-requests and can process beacon frames and probe replies.

It seems to be passive scanners are just active scanners with sending functionality disabled, is that correct way to see the things?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

While passive scanning is (mostly) a subset of active scanning, a passive scanner doesn't necessarily have active scanning functions. Note that passive scanning usually requires a network 'tap' to gather significant information while active scanning can work without - so the techniques are somewhat different.

Also, active scanning can be less or more intrusive - probing standard transport-layer ports for common services may already be considered intrusive by many, but massive probing of all possible ports definitely is.